# Unity / Objective-C: Trouble converting char* to NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine

I have what should be a dead-simple piece of code that is failing for me in strange ways.

```
void MediaShare(char* text, char* furl) {
    NSString *status = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: text];
    NSString *media = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: furl];

    [[SocialShare sharedInstance] mediaShare:status media:media];
```

text is just a line of text for Twitter sharing, and furl is just a file location string. I am getting a crash down past this function that comes down to bad data getting passed. Putting a breakpoint at the head of this function yields the following-

[Image of Xcode variable monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AafTt.png)

The two values look fine, although not sure if the * values that only contain the first char are a problem.

Anyway, jumping to the end, and status and media appear to be converted to hex values.

[Converted to hex values?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ls3p7.png)

Any ideas? To give the full story, this is a Unity plug-in. I am simply passing in two strings from Unity C# to this function.
Thanks so much.

Comment: Set a breakpoint before the mediaShare: call and look what you got in status and media.

Comment: According to https://manski.net/2012/06/pinvoke-tutorial-passing-strings-part-2/ `P/Invoke` pass UTF-16 in `char *`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks fine so far, if the input values are well formed C char* strings that can be interpreted as an UTF-8 encoded string.

`status` and `media` being hex values at the end of the function hint that they are. Both are pointers to Objective-C objects, so this is expected. Print them to the debug console or use `po status` at the debug console to check their contents (it will print the result of the `-description` method of `status` which is the string content in that case).

The subsequent crash might be caused elsewhere in the code.

What's the crash's log output?

Comment: Thanks, I was indeed misunderstanding the debugger and the crash was elsewhere in my own code. A few NSLogs showed me that these values were actually fine.